# Shortcut keys not working after messagebox is shown

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, key-bindings, inputbinding

I have a Window with Keybindings in InputBindings defined. They work the first time and when i set the focus on any control on the form.

But when a Messagbox is shown and I press "OK" they shortcut keys don't work until I set the focus on a control in my window.

My InputBindings:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+N" Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.NewMenuCommand}" />
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+O" Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.OpenMenuCommand}" />
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+S" Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.SaveMenuCommand}" />
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+Q" Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.CloseMenuCommand}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

My CommandBindings:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.NewMenuCommand}" Executed="NewEntity" />
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.OpenMenuCommand}" Executed="OpenEntity" />
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.SaveMenuCommand}" Executed="SaveEntity" />
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.CloseMenuCommand}" Executed="CloseEntity" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue while ago, it has something to do with the focus of your window but i actually found one hack to resolve it like this -

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Activated="HandleWindowActivated"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
```

And in your code behind put the focus on the window like this -

```
private void HandleWindowActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Focus();
}
```

Comment: It had to do with not defining the Parent/Owner of the Messagebox. By using 

    MessageBox.Show(Me, "Save")

In stead of:

    MsgBox("Save")

Made it fix this problem

Comment: Ok ,actually in my case i have implemented my custom message box and setting the parent/child relationship also didn't work for me. That's why i used the above approach..